# Making use of basic Java-knowledge, and where to go next

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have read almost the whole book "Java - A beginner's Guide" by Herbert Schildt (I skipped the more complex chapters about multithreadding, applets and Swing). So I am familiar with the basics of Java, i.e. writing classes, inheritance, and interfaces.

The problem I face at the moment is that I can't figure out a way to practice Java-programming (just reading books will not suffice), since I only use the console. It feels like I have the knowledge to write half-decently complex programs, but to no use: for example, I have the knowledge to create a program like John Conway's "Game of Life", but since I have no window to display graphics I can't practice Java by writing these programs.

My questions are consequently these:

- Need I spend several more hours learning graphics before I start practicing, or is there a better (i.e. more efficient) approach?
- If the answer to the question above is "no" (i.e. I do not need to learn graphics), what is the next chapter in Java that I should learn? Applets? Swing? Multithreadding?

Comment: One opinion that will probably be universal: forget about Applets. Also, you can do Game of Life in the console.

Comment: To do graphics in Java you need to learn at least SOME Swing.

Comment: Conway's Game of Life can certainly be implemented in a console. If you really want a graphical solution, maybe you shouldn't have skipped the chapter on Swing.

Comment: Ascii is often more fun than the applets

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - LWJGL/OpenGL - the OP can write an entire rendering engine from scratch using Java alone (without Swing) and just a little bit of basic GLSL is he wishes to implement shaders aswell. Fun project to try out especially if you just try to go for a 2D engine rather than a 3D one.

Comment: What are you interested in developing? Rich's answer below offers some pretty good basic coding exercises, but knowing what interests you might help narrow the search. Are you interested in building games? Web services/pages? REST APIs? A client/server application? etc...

Comment: My aim was to program Android applications, but then I decided that I might as well learn Java too. I have no visions for my Java-programming - but games are what I would have in mind if I'd have to choose something.

Comment: @Juxhin in that case I think you should write a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is useful for basic GUI applications. There are more complex solutions out there but Swing is not a bad place to start.

Eventually to have a responsive GUI you will want to learn about multithreading but you can get by without that if you're still learning. Without multithreading your GUI will appear to "hang" while your program is doing background work. Not a big deal for beginner learning but multithreading should probably be your next step after getting started with GUIs.

Also, there is plenty of practice you can do without writing a GUI, simple command line based programs can teach a lot and that is the vast majority of the work I remember doing in University. We did write the game of life in Swing, but we did lots more besides that. For example we implemented merge sort which would print the unsorted array, do the work, then print the sorted array. No GUI needed but learned a lot. We also did stuff like a DVD library (revealing my age) which accepted input from command line and stored data in a simple text file for retrieval later (with a few options for how you wanted it sorted). These are trivial examples but hopefully you can see from these that there are a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

Watch multiple videos on YouTube about Swing, enroll into an advanced course (which can be found for free), look up Java beginner exercises. Here is a link with multiple exercises for Java.  http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J2a_BasicsExercises.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a language called processing. This will skip over the hours of learning how to build applets ect, and make it very easy. You can even convert your java/processing code to javascript and run it on the web! https://processing.org/

Since the language is based on java, you can use all the basic java syntax, and use the simple, easy to use drawing commands and 3D libraries very effectively.